# Blanket stop CSS from cascading to a certain element not using iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an entire page that will be PHP included onto an already established website. The website will include my site after the `<body>` tag on their own site. I do not have access to the `<head>` section of the page. I am including my `<link>` and `<script>` tags in my page (so after the `<body>` of the parent page). I can change the title dynamically with javascript after the fact.

However, the CSS from the parent page is causing some interference with some of my elements that aren't explicitly styled. I would like a blanket way to stop CSS from cascading to my own elements without using an iframe. Is there a CSS reset that will work? How about a javascript solution?  Would HTML5 scoped styles fix this issue eventually?

Comment: I don’t think `link` inside `body` is valid even in HTML5. And no, scoped styles won’t help you here, because they work the other way around.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks. You're right, it's not valid, but browsers will still render it. The alternative, dynamically adding the `link` tags to the head through javascript after the page has loaded, will cause a brief flash of unstyled content until the CSS files load, as I understand it. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't give you a good answer. The closest I can think of is to take one of the [CSS Reset](http://www.cssreset.com/) scripts and apply them to your root `<div>`.

It's still a long list of things you're cancelling but at least it's maintained by someone else...

Comment: A variation on this technique is what I ended up having to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by wrapping content and appending CSS rules only to wrapped content, for example.

CSS

```
#wrapper1 .className{/* RULES */}
#wrapper1 div{/* RULES */}
#wrapper2 .className{/* OTHER RULES */}
#wrapper2 div{/* OTHER RULES */}
```

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper1">content 1</div>
<div id="wrapper2">content 2</div><!-- CONTENT YOU APPEND LATER -->
```

Another solution, not the best1 is maybe to use jQuery and replace all class-es or ID-s in body when content is changed, here again you should define CSS before.

There is one thing I must note, in my experience appending HTML as pure text (like innerHtml='html') get right CSS rules in Google Chrome and Mozilla, but on IE you need to use proper JS and append content differently to get those CSS rules used. By different I mean like creating element should really be creating new element with JS function.. that was before I am not sure anymore if this thing is changed.

Comment: I don't think this solves the OP's problem... If the "outer" page page has `table {border: solid 1px #f00;}` then all "inner" tables will still be styled with red borders. Specifically, jQuery would have no class to remove and if the CSS for the "established site" could be modified with impunity, there wouldn't be a problem in the first case.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but @Basic is correct. If the "outer" page has that style then unless I very specifically reset that exact style on the inner element it would display a red border. I'm looking for a way to fix the problem without specifically combating every single rule in the "outer" site's stylesheet that might affect me.

Comment: But why don't you try with wrapping...maybe it's not understood from written answer but I thought if you wrap for example tables into div and add UNIQUE ids to those div you could get that tables have custom CSS...and you define this CSS in main CSS...for example #wrapper1 table{some rules}...#wrapper2 table{some rules}...and when you change this content, this new content is wrappered with wrapper2..

Comment: @MrBr you're correct in what you're saying, but it won't help the situation. Your solution will have me manually target and change every single element that I have that is affected by the "outer" site's CSS and I'm looking for a generic way to accomplish this goal. It could be that there is no generic way, in which case I'll have to do something like what you suggest.

Comment: Hmm, I think i still don't understand problem..if problem is that some CSS is interfacing it means you will for sure have to define 2 times this CSS because it has to be different and you have the same element target..if you want 2 different CSS styles for same element it can not be done but to define it 2 times ? I see however where could be problem, and that is if you have some common CSS which apply to both content to some elements, then for those elements you can define CSS class or ID which doesn't depend on wrapper, and for that element you defined CSS only once.